# Unable to install fedup on Fedora 20

Tags: linux, fedora

I have an old Fedora 20 system. I'm trying to upgrade it to Fedora 21 following [Upgrading to Fedora 21 Workstation from Fedora 20](http://fedoramagazine.org/upgrading-to-fedora-21-workstation-from-fedora-20/). Its a small tutorial on Fedora's [Fedup tool](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedUp), which is the only offial/supported way to upgrade.

I can't seem to install `fedup`:

```
$ sudo yum install fedup fedora-release
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Package fedora-release-20-3.noarch already installed and latest version
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package fedup.noarch 0:0.9.1-1.fc20 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package        Arch            Version                  Repository        Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 fedup          noarch          0.9.1-1.fc20             updates           86 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 86 k
Installed size: 253 k
Is this ok [y/d/N]: Y
Downloading packages:
fedup-0.9.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm  FAILED                                          
http://mirror.unl.edu/fedora/linux/updates/20/x86_64/fedup-0.9.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirror.unl.edu"
Trying other mirror.
fedup-0.9.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm  FAILED                                          
http://mirror.uoregon.edu/fedora/linux/updates/20/x86_64/fedup-0.9.1-1.fc20.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirror.uoregon.edu"
Trying other mirror.
...
```

It appears every mirror is down.

I found a GitHub with the [sources to `fedup`](https://github.com/rhinstaller/fedup), but I can't install the prerequisites.

Am I missing a mirror with upgrade essential programs like `fedup`? (I can provide the full list of mirrors tried).

How do I install `fedup`? (Are there any historical mirrors that provide it? Can I install it by hand from somewhere?)

Answer (score 0):

This was a transient problem due to a (thankfully rare!) problem in the Fedora infrastructure. See [mirrorlist/metalink woes now fixed](http://www.scrye.com/wordpress/nirik/2015/06/20/mirrorlistmetalink-woes-now-fixed/) for a little background, with more to come when the event postmortem is finished.

In the meantime, this should work if you try again. You just hit it at an unfortunate time. (You also might want to keep a bookmark to http://status.fedoraproject.org/ handy — it will show all planned and unplanned downtime.)